# Specified cast is not valid while fetching column details from SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, ado.net

I am trying to fetch following details of columns from SQL Server:

- Size
- Precision
- Scale

I am successfully getting data when I have below schema for table:

**Table1:**

```
Col1 : varchar(40),null)
Col2 : varchar(2,null)
Col3 : varchar(57,null)
Col4 : varchar(245 ,null)
Col5 : datetime(not null)
```

But I'm getting an error

> Specified cast is not valid.

in case of this schema:

```
Col1 : varchar(34,null)
Col2 : varchar(1066,null)
Col3 : varchar(500,null)
Col4 : varchar(600,null)
Col5 : numeric(31,13,null)
Col6 : numeric(31,13,null)
Col7 : datetime(null)
```

Code:

```
String[] columnRestrictions = new String[4];
columnRestrictions[0] = 'MyDb';
columnRestrictions[1] = 'dbo';
columnRestrictions[2] = 'Employee';

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString"))
{
    con.Open();
    var columns = con.GetSchema("Columns", columnRestrictions).AsEnumerable()
         .Select
          (
                 t => new 
                 {
                     Name = t[3].ToString(),
                     Datatype = t.Field<string>("DATA_TYPE"),
                     IsNullable = t.Field<string>("is_nullable"),
                     Size = t.Field<int?>("character_maximum_length"),
                     NumericPrecision = t.Field<int?>("NUMERIC_PRECISION"), //error on this field
                     NumericScale = t.Field<int?>("NUMERIC_SCALE")
                 }).ToList();
```

Source :

[Reference1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff6ea9e2-89a0-42ea-88f5-98645d840999/microsoft-sql-server-informationschemacolumns-charactermaximumlength-is-null?forum=xmlandnetfx)

[Reference2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254969(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Update**: this line is causing the issue

```
NumericPrecision = t.Field<int?>("NUMERIC_PRECISION"), //error on this field
```

How can I resolve this error and fetch size, precision and scale for columns?

Comment: So which line is throwing the exception? You should narrow it down to a single field...

Comment: @JonSkeet:Name,Datatype,isnullable is working but i guess problem is with rest of the properties

Comment: Rather than guessing, you should do the work to narrow it down. Find one property which *definitely* causes a problem, and ideally in the debugger work out what the *actual* type is.

Comment: @JonSkeet:I have identified the property which is causing the issue.see my updated question

Comment: @MarcGravell : I have updated my question to include which line is causing the issue.When i comment out the last 2 property then i am successfully getting name,datatype and nullable

Comment: In  sys.columns, `precision` and `scale` are `tinyint`, which maps to `byte`. You could always just look at the underlying value or the column def - `GetSchema()` returns a   `DataTable`, which has `.Columns["NUMERIC_PRECISION"].DataType`

Comment: @MarcGravell :Yes thank you so much you are right.i have 1 column with datatype as varchar(max) then using character_maximum_length i get -1 for this.Can you tell me why -1 in case of max varchar??

Comment: @Learning because -1  is the setinel value it uses to denote `max`

Comment: @MarcGravell:Thank you so much marc.i have seen your lots of answer and as you are 1 of the best user of SO so i had a wished that you will answer my question 1 day so my wish is partially fullfilled with your comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are casting a `byte` to `int?`, the `Field`-method supports nullable types (if the column can be null), but it doesn't convert  from `byte?` to `int?`. It throws this exception instead. [Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/DataRowExtensions.cs,5d2e489d93a52c65,references)

So just use this:

```
NumericPrecision = t.Field<byte?>("NUMERIC_PRECISION"),
```

You can always look at the `DataColumn`'s `DataType` property.